# Olaf K. Storaasli Master's/Doctor's Theses, Princeton/Temple University (Schools of Theology)

Tags: graduate-school, thesis, masters, university

How can I find a copy of my Dad's Seminary Master's/Doctor's Theses at Princeton/Temple Universities in 1942/1944. His name: Olaf K. Storaasli

Comment: I’d start with contacting the librarians at the respective institutions. Note that the Princeton Seminary is independent of Princeton University.

Comment: Jon Custer: This seems to be the answer to me.

Comment: The premise of the question is fine, but my understanding of the site guidelines is that we try to edit questions so that they could apply to more than one person's situation.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How to Access an American PhD Thesis?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37585/how-to-access-an-american-phd-thesis) Or even: [How can I find an old, obscure, or otherwise inaccessible paper when the usual methods fail?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/)

Comment: Question is not interesting for the broad audience. You can reformulate it in a way that will receive answer that may be useful for other people apart from your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Google Scholar indicates there is a Storaasli, Olaf Kenneth. *The Idea of" Soteria" in the Synoptic Gospels*. Diss. Princeton Theological Seminary, 1942. And [here's](https://catalog.ptsem.edu/record=b1603415%7ES1) the record in the catalog of Wright Library at Princeton Theological Seminary. The location given for their copy is "Second Floor - Special Collections" and the status is "Use in Library". If you are unable to visit the library, you can try contacting the librarians and ask if it would be possible to acquire a scanned version.

I do not find a mention of the dissertation at Temple University on their library website. However, using the ProQuest dissertation database I find a record (ProQuest ID 301831003) of the dissertation (but not the full text) listed under the title "THE GOSPEL AS EXPRESSED IN THE CHORALE" and the year 1945. Like Jon Custer suggests in a comment, contacting librarians at Temple seems like the best lead.